# Pushing json to array return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a little problem with javascript here. I've been searching but with no luck. So I have the following json object:

```
{
  core: {
      repositoryformatversion: '0',
      filemode: 'true',
      bare: 'false',
      logallrefupdates: 'true'
  },
  'remote "origin"': {
      fetch: '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*',
      url: 'https://github.com/user/repo.git'
  },
  'branch "master"': {
      remote: 'origin',
      merge: 'refs/heads/master'
  }
}
```

and here is my script:

```
var iniparser = require('iniparser');
var result = [];

iniparser.parse('analytics.js/.git/config', function(err,data){
   result.push(data);
});

console.log(result);
```

it returns `[]`. Actually, I want to push just the url (https://github.com/user/repo.git) by using `result.push(data['remote "origin"'].url)`.
when I use `console.log(data['remote "origin"'].url)` it returns the url correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/. Not an exact match, but you're experiencing the same problem just from different tasks.

Comment: @KevinBoucher but when I log that, it returns correctly. or any other suggestion?

Comment: @rizqy22 `iniparser` may be more lenient in its parsing than [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [similar](http://json.org/). But, you should plan for stricter parsing and make sure your JSON is valid. Including: all object keys must be strings and all strings are double-quoted: `{ "core": { ... }, "remote \"origin\"": { ... }, ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using [none-iniparser](https://github.com/shockie/node-iniparser)?

if so it looks like `parse` is asyncronous (i'm judging by the callback, and that there is a `parseSync` function.

This means that you dont really know when the callback will be invoked. `parse` is called ,then your program instantly moves to `console.log` the `result`, which hasn't changed yet. THEN at some time, whenever `parse` is finished, the parse callback is invoked

Comment: nice! you saved my day, I never thought about that and now its working, thank you :)